# How to specify a php log file using syslog-ng

Tags: php, centos6, syslog, syslog-ng

Within my PHP script, I have a line printing output to syslog, much like the one below:

```
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Writing log info to syslog");
```

By default, it prints output to /var/log/messages. Is there anyway to change the output file to be something different? I am using syslog-ng and a CentOS 6 server.

Comment: Think you have to change it in `syslog-ng.conf` in linux, not possible to do this with php

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions syslog-ng.conf is not the same as syslog.conf. Those options are not present.

Comment: OK, i only want to give the hint, thats only possible on linux level, not within PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing (really) to do with PHP. You're not wring to a "file" - you're sending your log entry to the syslog daemon, "here's something for the log named LOG_INFO", and the syslog daemon decides where that should go.

If you want to target a specific file, you'd have to set a LOG_XXXX target to point to that file in the syslog configuration - you can't have PHP tell syslog which file it should use directly.

If you do want specific file targeting, then use [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) instead, where you CAN specify the filename to log to.